# Spring @Autowired annotation

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have been trying the following simple source code with Autowired annotation.

---

TextEditor.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class TextEditor {
    private SpellChecker spellChecker;

    @Autowired
    public void setSpellChecker( SpellChecker spellChecker ){
      this.spellChecker = spellChecker;
    }
    public SpellChecker getSpellChecker( ) {
      return spellChecker;
    }
    public void spellCheck() {
      spellChecker.checkSpelling();
    }
}
```

---

SpellChecker.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class SpellChecker {
   public SpellChecker(){
      System.out.println("Inside SpellChecker constructor." );
   }

   public void checkSpelling(){
      System.out.println("Inside checkSpelling." );
   }

}
```

---

MainApp.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = 
             new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

      TextEditor te = (TextEditor) context.getBean("textEditor");

      te.spellCheck();
   }
}
```

---

Beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config/>

   <!-- Definition for textEditor bean without constructor-arg  -->
   <bean id="textEditor" class="com.tutorialspoint.TextEditor">
   </bean>

   <!-- Definition for spellChecker bean -->
   <bean id="spellChecker" class="com.tutorialspoint.SpellChecker">
   </bean>
```

But I get the following error. I am a beginner of Spring framework. If somebody helps me, I will really appreciate. Thanks.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire      method: public void    com.tutorialspoint.TextEditor.setSpellChecker(com.tutorialspoint.SpellChecker); nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getParameterAnnotations()[Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectMethods(InjectionMetadata.java:117)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:253)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getParameterAnnotations()[Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.getAnnotations(DependencyDescriptor.java:203)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:377)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:364)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:670)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:499)
... 18 more
```

Comment: Could you please show which dependency do you use in your build system? Or could you please ensure that you have no conflicts in your dependencies?

Comment: +1 to Taky. All the spring jars in your classpath don't have the same version.

Comment: I think using a combination of XML and Annotation based config is not the best way to go. In fact, if you are learning Spring - avoid XML altogether. XML is now (more or less) deprecated when it comes to configuring Spring.

Comment: Reference libraries are the following                        commons-logging-1.1.2.jar
org.springframework.beans-2.5.5.a.jar
org.springframework.context-2.5.5.a.jar
org.springframework.context-sources-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M2.jar

Comment: So, you have your answer. If you want to use version 3.2.5, then all spring jars should have version 3.2.5. Not 3.1.0.M2 or 2.5.5.a. Not that the current version is 4.0.1.